# Pandas Create DF for Table

Tags: pandas, format, callable

i'm trying to create a table but first a DF that has the elements i need for the table and I get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-400-241c1509eba9>", line 4, in <module>
[c1.iloc[:,1]],

TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

This is the command I'm using to create the new DF "c1t":

```
c1t = pd({
"Range": ["50-75%", "75-90%", "90-110%",
"110-125%","125-150%"],"adjusted_power": [c1.iloc[:,0]],"counts":
 [c1.iloc[:,1]],
}).set_index("Range")
```

Here is the DF "c1":

```
       adjusted_power  counts
0   (9694.2, 14541.2]       2
1  (14541.2, 17449.5]       3
2  (17449.5, 21327.2]      20
3  (21327.2, 24235.4]       3
4  (24235.4, 29082.5]       1

type(c1)
Out[412]: pandas.core.frame.DataFrame
```

My assumption that DF "c1" is callable must be false since I"m getting the callable error but I'm not sure how to include "c1" for the new DF (c1t). Thank you,

Answer (score 0):

To create the new dataframe `c1t` the same as `c1` but with an index you can assign it (which returns a copy) and set the index on this copy:

```
c1t = c1.set_index(pd.Index(["50-75%", "75-90%", "90-110%","110-125%","125-150%"], name='Range'))
```